# Python search string value from file

Tags: python, search, match

I'm trying to create a python script to look up for a specific string in a txt file
For example I have the text file dbname.txt includes the following :

```
Level1="50,90,40,60"
Level2="20,10,30,80"
```

I will need the script to search for the user input in the file and print the output that equals that value Like :

```
Please enter the quantity : 50
The level is : Level1
```

I am stuck in the search portion from the file ?
any advise ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would use a mix of file and CSV.  Are you familiar?

Comment: You should open the file, then you can use readlines() and can go through line by line using a loop. Then, you can try startswith() to match your input. Finally, you can try find or any other string stuff to match that!

Comment: untill now i finished all the lines but i don't know the command to make the search or match operation , for the csv file i do know how to use it . any suggestions ?

Comment: @jollarvia: why would you try to use mix of two things? do you mean split?

Comment: So, are you looking for command to search? Do some exercises on startswith() and find() or some other basic stuffs. You will be able to solve it. Cheers!

Comment: how about using `regex`?

Comment: How do you find my solution, abualameer94?

Comment: I found an issue with my answer and corrected it, I must not have posted the code I tested. My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

In these sorts of limited cases, I would recommend regular expressions.

```
import re
import os
```

You need a file to get the info out of, make a directory for it, if it's not there, and then write the file:

```
os.mkdir = '/tmp' 
filepath = '/tmp/foo.txt'
with open(filepath, 'w') as file:
    file.write('Level1="50,90,40,60"\n'
               'Level2="20,10,30,80"')
```

Then read the info and parse it:

```
with open(filepath) as file:
    txt = file.read()
```

We'll use a regular expression with two capturing groups, the first for the Level, the second for the numbers:

```
mapping = re.findall(r'(Level\d+)="(.*)"', txt)
```

This will give us a list of tuple pairs. Semantically I'd consider them keys and values. Then get your user input and search your data:

```
user_input = raw_input('Please enter the quantity: ')
```

I typed 50, and then:

```
for key, value in mapping:
    if user_input in value:
        print('The level is {0}'.format(key))
```

which prints:

```
The level is Level1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the mmap module, the most efficient way to do this hands down. mmap doesn't read the entire file into memory (it pages it on demand) and supports both find() and rfind()

```
with open("hello.txt", "r+b") as f:
    # memory-map the file, size 0 means whole file
    mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
    position = mm.find('blah')
```